# How to pass meta_value in WordPress query posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to pass meta_value in query posts in wordpress.

Here coding I tried but not working.

```
<?php
           $db_highest = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'rating_count'
ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1000")); 

  global $wp_query;

               query_posts(array(

                    'paged' => $wp_query->get('paged'),

                    'post_type' => array('company'),


                    'posts_per_page' => $opt_metrodir_company_list_count,

                    'meta_query' => array(

                      'meta_value' => $db_highest

            ));


           ?>
```

I want to use meta_value query so I get descending order of rating value count like 10,8,5,4,3,2,1
I want to display posts who has highest rating.
if I print_r($db_highest); then it display below results.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 1
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 1
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 1
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 
        )

)
```

So in the end My result will be like this

```
query_posts(array(

                    'paged' => $wp_query->get('paged'),

                    'post_type' => array('company'),


                    'posts_per_page' => $opt_metrodir_company_list_count,

                    'meta_query' => array(

                      'meta_value' => array(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)

                        ));
```

Comment: so you want to convert print_r($db_highest);  into array(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) ??

Comment: I want to display company posts in rating order like highest comes first.

Comment: Please apply the array_unique function